# Why is Firebase Hosting adding 1.0 second to my Cloud Run server response times?

Tags: firebase, server-side-rendering, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I have a web app hosted on Firebase Hosting and it rewrites every request to a Cloud Run service that runs an express server.

**firebase.json**

```
"rewrites": [{
  "source": "**",
  "run": { 
    "serviceId": "server", 
    "region": "europe-west1"
  }
}],
```

Users get the regular `index.html` file containing the `<script>` tags for the JS bundles, because my app is a client-rendered SPA (single page app). All those static files are being cached on Firebase Hosting CDN, and they are served really fast (like 30 to 100ms).

But my server does SSR for robots. And those responses are not cached. So, whenever a bot (like Googlebot) comes visit, the response will come from my server (to guarantee fresh data) and not from the CDN.

[image]

The SSR responses (testing from my browser) are usually taking around 1.5 to 2 seconds, which I think is a bit too long, as you can see in the image above.

When I inspect the logs from Cloud Run, I can see that those responses are taking around 300 to 400ms (image below).

[image]

So why is it taking 1.5 to 2.0 seconds to reach my browser? If the response is generated within 400ms, where is that extra 1.0 second being spent on? Is Firebase taking too long to make the rewrite in and out?

**EXTRA**

When I hit the Cloud Run URL directly (bypassing the Firebase Hosting connected custom domain), I get a response in around 150ms (image below).

[image]

That response is a 302 redirect because my server is configured to redirect any calls that are made directly to its URL (i.e.: without passing through Firebase Hosting). This makes sure my app is only accessible from its connected domains. But still, even if we add 150ms + 350ms (from the actual SSR response), it would be 500ms, which is way less than the 1.5 seconds it takes to respond through Firebase Hosting.

Is this normal?

Comment: Did you try different regions? `us-central1`, etc…? Also, depending on your use case you may want to consider CDN caching by setting appropriate Cache HTTP headers…

Firebase Hosting uses Fastly CDN, and somehow origin pulls are extremely slow…

Comment: When you hit the Cloud Run directly, I understand there is no data getting served by the server (response 302). Can this cause the difference in times? How heavy is the data served? I mean the one that is usually cached. Also, are the locations of the Googlebot and the server far from each other?